# How to reinject JavaScript when a react-native-webview reloads?

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview

To work properly, we need to inject certain functions into a webview we integrated in our React Native App. If the webview reloads, the javascript needs to be re-injected accordingly. How is this possible?

The javascript should be injected into the webview not only until the webview reloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main idea is to use ***injectJavaScript*** on page load.

```
const App = () => {
  const webViewRef = React.useRef<WebView>(null);
  const reloadsCount = React.useRef<number>(0);
  const onLoadInjected = `
    window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
      window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage('InjectNewCode');
    });
  `;

  const injectNewJsCode = () => {
    webViewRef.current?.injectJavaScript(`alert('new code injected')`)
    reloadsCount.current++
  }

  return (
    <WebView
      ref={ webViewRef }
      pullToRefreshEnabled={ true }
      source={{
        uri: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74386954/how-to-reinject-javascript-when-a-react-native-webview-reloads',
      }}
      onMessage={ ({ nativeEvent }) => {
        if (nativeEvent.data === 'InjectNewCode') {
          // skip the inital load event
          if (reloadsCount.current > 0) {
            injectNewJsCode()
          }
          reloadsCount.current++
        }
      }}
      injectedJavaScript={ onLoadInjected }
    />
  );
};
```